# Перехват throw в JS

Tags: javascript

Возникла задача написания кода, который перехватывал бы любые исключения и ошибки JS в браузере, в том числе, ошибки, сгенерированные вручную при помощи `throw window.onerror` на это, увы, не способен. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, или, может, знает, как её решить?

UPD:
Как оказалось, `window.onerror` перехватывает `throw`, но `window.onerror` можно перезаписать, что в моей ситуации если не неприемлемо, то крайне нежелательно. Поэтому изначально я планировал использовать для этой цели `addEventListener`, но, как назло, он, по всей видимости, не перехватывает `throw`. Может кто-то знает какие-то еще способы?

UPD:
Прошу прощения у всех, кого побеспокоил за ложный вызов. Ситуация оказалась следущей: И `window.onerror`, и `addEventListener` успешно перехватывают `throw`, но только, когда они вызваны через глобальный код. Допустим, через `onclick`, или в теге `<script>`. Если же вызвать `throw` в консоли, то ничего не произойдет. Равно, как и если написать код с неправильным синтаксисом, или с вызовом неопределенной переменной или функции. С меня всем по плюсику, вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо!

Comment: В каком окружении? Браузер? Нода?

Comment: похоже что никак, ошибки надо ловить в тех методах где они могут произойти. Какое может быть практическое применения глобального перехватчика?

Comment: @Grundy, Долгая история...

Comment: @AlexeyTen, В браузере. Разве в Ноде есть window.onerror?

Comment: Действительно. Зато в ноде как раз есть https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception :)

Comment: onerror перехватывает throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял -

```js
window.addEventListener('error', event => {
  console.log(`ошибка перехвачена: ${event.error.toString()}`);
});

throw "some exception";
```

```js
window.addEventListener('error', event => { 
  console.log(`ошибка перехвачена: ${event.error.toString()}`);
});

notExistsProp.notExistsMethod();
```

И пример иллюстрирующий работу `onerror` -

```js
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  console.log(`ошибка перехвачена: ${errorMsg}`);
}

throw "some exception";
```

Comment: Не работает. Попробуйте, запустите. Кстати, что за такая странная конструкция в вызове addEventListener во втором аргументе?

Comment: Работает, у меня!)

Comment: @Крендель, es6 arrow function, и es6 template string. Это конструкции в новом коде уже совсем не странные, к ним пора привыкать)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Ясно... А как эта конструкция ведет себя в IE7, например?

Comment: @Крендель, громко падает, как почти все в IE7. Если вам нужно поддерживать IE7 я вам очень соболезную. Если же ваша поддержка IE9+, то для поддержки такой конструкции (и еще много чего еще) есть этап сборки на котором гоняется транспайлер (бабель обычно) который превращает красивый и удобный код в некрасивый но работающий.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Конкретно мне нужна поддержка ios7+. Про IE спросил только для интереса

Comment: @Крендель, http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ - таблица поддержки из коробки, там можете найти ваш движок, можете найти бабель и поизучать. Новый официальный стандарт где есть стрелочки _официально_ вышел уже полтора года назад, а используется еще плюс год как минимум. Можно весь сахар и не использовать из каких-то соображений, но удивляться  ему уж точно хватит)

Comment: @Крендель, если кратко то код отранспиленный бабелем должен нормально гоняться там где достаточно хорошо поддерживается es5 (для IE это 8-9, для ios не знаю), для более старых браузеров возможно тоже есть решение, но мне его искать не приходилось

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, Да уж... давно я не смотрел what's new... чувствую себя динозавром 

Comment: @Крендель, https://webapplog.com/es6/

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, Спасибо, почитаю на досуге.